# Help identifying an error type "tried to help me learning"

Tags: grammar, infinitives, gerunds, present-participles

I have a friend from Russia who is trying to learn English and recently used the sentence "He tried to help me learning..." (implied: the English language)

It is obviously wrong and I corrected it telling her that she was supposed to say: "He tried to help me learn.", but I have a hard time explaining to her *why* it is incorrect since I'm not an expert on grammar either.

Is it a case of confusing the present simple and present continuous or does it have something to do with gerunds and infinitives? Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Could you complete the sentence and add what your correction would be? I'm not convinced that it is necessarily wrong.

Comment: His mistake makes even less sense seeing how in Russian, too, you'd use the infinitive in that position. Perhaps you should start by pointing *that* out to him and asking what his justification for the present participle is at all.

Comment: She just told me that she knew a guy from GB once who "tried to help her learning." and my correction was: "Tried to help you learn."
Thanks so far!

Comment: In "He tried to help her learning," *learning* could be a gerund.

Comment: But wouldn't it be "He tried to help her with learning," then?

Comment: Not necessarily. Back to the question: is there anything to follow after "learning..." or should that be a full stop?

Comment: That was the end of the sentence, but the implication is "the English language". That's what he was trying to help her with.

Comment: Could you edit your question so it's complete, please?

Comment: "He tried to help her learning." Yes, "learning" is a gerund. Byt, "He tried to help me learning" does not work. If "learning" is a gerund here, then what role does "me" play in the sentence? You could say "He tried to help MY learning". But regardless, it's far cleaner to say, "He tried to help me learn."

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with the type of catenation patterns *help* governs.

Many verbs in English catenate (form allowed strings):

He sat reading.

He started to cry.

He helped wash up.

He helped to wash up.

He helped us wash up.

He helped us to wash up.

There are several patterns, and different patterns are allowed for different verbs.

"He tried to help me learning..." has a string of three catenated verbs, with an interposed object (me). The first catenation (He tried to help [me] ) is fine - *tried* catenates with a to-infinitive, as here, or an -ing form (obviously, the -ing form has to be nearer the verbal, participial, end of the spectrum for catenation of verbs to apply - see below). They have slightly different meanings.

However, *help* normally catenates with a bare infinitive or to-infinitive, so "He tried to help me learn..." or "He tried to help me to learn..." would be used.

*Help* does catenate in one construction with an -ing form: I can't help loving you - but *help* here means avoid / give up.
*Help* also appears in similar-looking constructions with more-nounal -ing forms: This drug is given to help breathing.

A good article is at http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_catenative_verbs - although the 'present participle/gerund form' mysteriously suddenly narrows to the 'gerund form'. The Quirk umpteen-point gradience along the verb - noun continuum for -ing forms is, I believe, a more accurate model, so I prefer the cover term '-ing form'.

That's the grammar, but using the infinitives loses the progressive sense. A rewrite would be:

I was learning English - and he was trying to help me.

Or, if we do not wish to stress a continued duration of the attempt to help:

I was learning English - and he tried to help me.

Answer (score 3):

In the sentence you wrote, *learning* is a gerund, not present continuous; the present continuous would be "she is learning."

*Help* is normally used as in the following sentences:

> Mary's companion **helped her with** the rent.

> She **helped him find** a buyer.

> Mary **helped out** in the corner store.

Searching for phrases matching `help <personal pronoun> <gerund>` on the *Corpus of Contemporary American English*, I found the following sentences.

> Stephanie was able to identify notes, but it didn't **help her playing**.

> If not, there are other tricks he can try: spinning the hull against the sphere's fixed inner platform, or even God **help them popping** open the hatch to serve as a kind of fin or rudder.

> My triffle is to **help me following** you, so we get there.

> And at certain point, I decided I couldn't make a great deal of difference in the world of chess anymore, but my presence in Russia, in my native land, could **help us fighting** for democracy.

> So, this only tells us about the survivors and it can't really **help us making** the decisions at the bedside.

Those sentences are very minimal, compared with the phrase matching `help <personal pronoun> <infinitive>`.

Notice that *cannot help*, and *could not help* are used to also mean *cannot avoid*, and *could not avoid*, as in the following sentences:

> She could not help laughing.

> You can't help but agree.

*Cannot help oneself*, and *could not help oneself* are used to mean "cannot stop oneself from acting in a certain way," and "could not stop oneself from acting in a certain way" as in the following sentence.

> She couldn't help herself; she burst into tears.

Answer (score 3):

The confusion arises because of the way English uses the [gerund](http://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-gerunds.htm), a noun identical in form to the present participle.  It is possible (though in my view unidiomatic) to use *help my learning* to mean roughly the same as *help my education*. Note that though you can say *help my educating*, you can't use it here; it would mean *help me to educate other people*.

However, precisely because a gerund is a noun, the pronoun before it would be *my*, not *me*. So the gerund form is, in fact a red herring; there is no way
'he helped me learning' can be grammatical.

(A further source of confusion is that *her* does not inflect, so both *he helped her learn* and *he helped her learning* are grammatical, though they mean different things; but this is not important for the main point.)

Comment: I'm not sure I disagree with anything in kiamlaluno's answer, but I think you've put your finger on the key point. You can *help **him in** learning English*, and (just about) *help **his** learning English*, but whilst not unknown, OP's version doesn't really pass muster to the careful native speaker's ear.