# Which is correct: "your -ing" or "you -ing"?

Tags: grammar

Which of the following is (more) correct or are they both acceptable?

> I apologise for **your** receiving emails.

or

> I apologise for **you** receiving emails.

I *think* I read somewhere (but can't find the reference) that the first one is more correct.

Comment: Neither makes any sense unless the sentence continues with e.g. "... receiving spam e-mails apparently sent by me" or "... receiving emails from me after asking to be removed from my mailing list." Else, why are you apologising that I receive e-mails?!

Comment: Also related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/81525/8019

Comment: Thanks @TimLymington and @RegDwigh; I had a feeling there was already a question about this (but just didn't know what keywords to search).

Comment: To me, both versions turn the apology on its head. Why should **I** apologize for something **you** are doing? Why not just say, "I apologize for emailing you" or "I apologize for any inconvenience my email caused you"?

Answer (score -2):

As a native english speaker I would say the second one sounds more correct, because in the first case I feel it would have to be "I apologise for your reception of emails." Since your is possessive there would have to be a noun following.

Comment: But there *is* a noun following.